# Aliquot results after division

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get results with no aliquot + addig the percent mark to them.

I'm using below row code:

```
(cast(step_out_quantity as float) / step_in_quantity *100.00) as Yield
```

My output column looks like this:

```
Yield
57.1428571428571
100
100
100
87.5
100
90.9090909090909
98.1132075471698
99.1525423728814
93.3333333333333
```

What is my best option to achieve the next results:

```
Yield
57%
100%
100%
100%
87%
100%
```

Comment: Sorry...sql-server

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL you can do:

```
select concat(cast(cast(step_out_quantity*100 as int
                       ) / step_in_quantity as varchar(255)
                  ), '%'
             ) as Yield
```

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
select cast(floor(step_out_quantity * 100) as varchar(255)) + '%'
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply.
I tried to use the code you sent me but I'm getting the next error:
Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'.

Comment: @Coldfire please follow this [link when someone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;).